# Evaluate $ (\forall y)(\exists x)(x \times x = y) $

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

$\times$ is as you would think, the multiplication operation.

$ (\forall y)(\exists x)(x \times x = y) $

For the domains $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ I found this formula fairly simple to evaluate, false in both cases.

I'm not certain with the following domains:

**Domain:** $\mathbb{Q}$

With this domain I concluded it evaluated to false, as for y=2, the $\sqrt[]{2}$ is not a rational number.

Is that correct?

**Domain:** $\mathbb{R}$

Would this evaluate to true, based off every real number $y$ having a real square root $x$?

Comment: Not every real number has a real square root

Comment: @Henry Example?

Comment: Write down a bunch of random real numbers that feel like a good sample and ask yourself or a calculator what their square root is. Don't just imagine doing this - actually do it.

Comment: @0implies0 - it might be more enlightening if you found an example yourself

Comment: $i \not\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Henry Ah, right the square root of a negative number is imaginary.

Comment: @MarkS. So if y = -1, there exists no real number x such that x × x = -1

Comment: But, if the domain is $\mathbb{C}$, then the statement would be true.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Good point, that rules out it being a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks everyone! To conclude, this formula is false for domains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Might be worthwhile putting that into a self answer, so that people looking at new questions know that this one has been resolved.

Comment: @user400188 Done. Should I accept it or leave it as is? I am unsure about accepting my own answer .

Comment: @0implies0 It's perfectly fine to accept your own answer (actually preferable, since it marks the question as resolved), although I believe that stack exchange requires a 48 wait before it can be done (this is automatic). No reputation will be awarded for accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the users in the comment section:

> "Not every real number has a real square root" - @Henry

I have worked out that indeed this formula would evaluate to **false** for domains $ \mathbb{Q} $ (take y=2) and $\mathbb{R} $ (take y=-1). In both domains, no such x exists.